# Delete tracked files just cloned from Git in the wrong folder

Tags: github

I was pulling a project on GitHub and accidentally dropped all assets in `My Documents`.

While there are ways in explorer to toss all these files, is there an easy way in Git to just get rid of just the files cloned *without* removing any other files?

Comment: By "pull" do you mean you cloned it directly into "My Documents" folder?

Comment: @Saravana I suspect so, and have rewritten the question accordingly. If Skyler disagree, the question can still be edited.

Comment: yea @Saravana I made my dir and then initialized git and downloaded everything from the repo before changing directories into the project folder

Answer (score 1):

Try resetting (if you don't have any local modification to existing tracked file) to the previous state before the `git pull`:

```
git reset --hard HEAD@{1}
```

But if you have clone/pull a repo in the wrong folder, without touching other untracked files, [see this set of commands](https://superuser.com/a/450115/141):

```
git ls-files -z | xargs -0 rm -f
git ls-tree --name-only -d -r -z HEAD | sort -rz | xargs -0 rmdir
```

That way, yoiu are deleting the tracked files with `My Documents`